# mongodb not starting from command line in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, shortcuts, mongodb

> `Path` is where Windows finds executables, learned from [MongoDB](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about).

So, on my 64 bit Windows 7 - I have added the location of MongoDB's startup path:

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`

to the `Path` System variable.

[image: mongodb path variable]

However, when I try to run it from command line - I get the following error:

[image: Mongo is not the command]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Environment variables are only updated when you do a Windows Reboot. So to get the path working, reboot Windows. Now you can run the command

Comment: Just closing the cmd window and opening again would do the job. No need to reboot!

Comment: @WaqasShah you added a user variable, system variable requires reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to close the cmd and open it again to reload the PATH variable.

Check your path variable in the cmdline with `path`to see if it is properly set.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to start MongoDB from the file it's in. You're typing the command from Users/zanzari and I think you have to navigate to the bin it's in and type mondod.exe

Type cd .. enter, cd .. enter, which will take you to C:\  and then type cd program files\mongodb\server\3.2\bin enter, then type mongod.exe

Setting the path variable does nothing for me.